# VDB render in cycles has blocky artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

so i used this VDB on my scene, and rendered it with cycles.
but somehow it has this blocky artifacts

[image]

what is the cause and how do i solve it ?
I rendered it with 1024 samples and denoised it with optix.

Comment: i'm rendering with cycles so i dont have that options, the options you mentioned is for eevee

Comment: You're right. In this case it is probably that the resolution of your simulation is too low, but you can also test if reducing the Step Rate Render (*Render Properties > Volumes*) helps.